# How To Put FontAwesome In Inner.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How am I suppose to put **fontawesome** icon i.e

```
`<i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

`in a place of "Info" in below inner.html 
Below is my javascript

```
dlg.innerHTML = "<span class='alert-headingg'>Info<" + "/span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this You have to just put your icon element inside your span.It will work for you.

```
dlg.innerHTML = "<span class='alert-headingg'><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="icon-github"></i>

div.github:before
{
   content: "\f09b";
   font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```